# some dynamic dropdownlists don't update -- autopostback = true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page that has developed an issue with only some of the dropdownlists. As indicated autopostback = true and yes I'm accounting for the !postback.

Line of Business, Director and Agent all post back without issue but the Senior Manager and Manager postback with the first value on the list regardless of selection.

here is the asp

```
<asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1" Width="17%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblLob" runat="server">Line Of Business: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbLoB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>   
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLoB" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cmbLoB" InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="Please select a Line of Business"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                   
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>       
            <asp:TableCell ID="tcRange" CssClass="tc1" runat="server" Width="15%">            
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateRange" runat="server">Report Range: </asp:Label>            
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbDateRange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>    
        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1"><asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date: "></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender
                ID="calStartDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1"><asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date: "></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender
                ID="calEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd"></asp:CalendarExtender>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>        
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1" Width="17%">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDirector" runat="server">Senior Leader: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbDirector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>                      
            </asp:TableCell>    
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1" Width="17%" ID="tdlblAggregate" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAggregate" runat="server">Aggregation Level: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1" ID="tdcmbAggregate" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbAggregate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect">
                <asp:ListItem Value="LoB" Text="Segment"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="SM" Text="Senior Manager"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>                      
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow> 
        <asp:TableRow>           
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSManager" Visible="true" runat="server">Senior Manager: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSManager" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>                      
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow> 
        <asp:TableRow>            
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblManager" Visible="true" runat="server">Manager: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbManager" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>                      
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>            
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAgent" Visible="true" runat="server">Associate/Specialist: </asp:Label>              
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tc1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbAgent" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="reSelect"></asp:DropDownList>                      
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
```

And the code behind:

```
            DataTable SLTSelectDistinct = SLTSelect.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "sltID", "sltName");
            DataView sltSelect = new DataView(SLTSelectDistinct);
            DataRow sltRow = SLTSelectDistinct.NewRow();
            sltRow[0] = "0";
            sltRow[1] = "-- Please Select --";
            SLTSelectDistinct.Rows.Add(sltRow);

            sltSelect.Sort = "sltName";
            cmbDirector.DataValueField = "sltID";
            cmbDirector.DataTextField = "sltName";
            cmbDirector.DataSource = sltSelect;
            cmbDirector.DataBind();

            DataTable SMSelectDistinct = SMSelect.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "smID", "smName");
            DataView smSelect = new DataView(SMSelectDistinct);
            DataRow smRow = SMSelectDistinct.NewRow();
            smRow[0] = "0";
            smRow[1] = "-- Please Select --";
            SMSelectDistinct.Rows.Add(smRow);

            smSelect.Sort = "smName";
            cmbSManager.DataValueField = "smID";
            cmbSManager.DataTextField = "smName";
            cmbSManager.DataSource = smSelect;
            cmbSManager.DataBind();

            DataTable MSelectDistinct = MSelect.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "mID", "mName");
            DataView mSelect = new DataView(MSelectDistinct);
            DataRow mRow = MSelectDistinct.NewRow();
            mRow[0] = "0";
            mRow[1] = "-- Please Select --";
            MSelectDistinct.Rows.Add(mRow);

            mSelect.Sort = "mName";
            cmbManager.DataValueField = "mID";
            cmbManager.DataTextField = "mName";
            cmbManager.DataSource = mSelect;
            cmbManager.DataBind();

            DataTable ASelectDistinct = LoBSelect.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "C_AGT", "aName");
            DataView aSelect = new DataView(ASelectDistinct);
            DataRow aRow = ASelectDistinct.NewRow();
            aRow[0] = "0";
            aRow[1] = "-- Please Select --";
            ASelectDistinct.Rows.Add(aRow);

            aSelect.Sort = "aName";
            cmbAgent.DataValueField = "C_AGT";
            cmbAgent.DataTextField = "aName";
            cmbAgent.DataSource = aSelect;
            cmbAgent.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is Databind, is called in !Page.Postback...??

Comment: all that I have posted is handled in the "reSelect" noted in the asp code.  I've triple checked that I'm not entering into the postback on the "reSelect".

Comment: What method are we looking at? It's more beneficial to post entire code (methods should include signature, any javascript, etc) to make this more useful.

Comment: Please post the HTML that is generated in the browser for these dropdowns.

Comment: Why do you have autopostback on every drop down.  You only need it on one control in your page.  This is causing the page to post back to the server every time you do anything on any of those drop downs.

Comment: Thnx to the suggestion to post the HTML code.  I found the issue.  appreciate all the input. feeling a little foolish haha..

Comment: Oh.. the autopostback.. it's on everywhere because depending on the selection of the dropdown it will clear or repopulate the dropdown... it's not the best method I know but for what I have for hardware is not even as good as my home desktop... just making things work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably that you have 0 as the value of one of your actual options as well so when the page refreshes the selected value of the dropdown is 0 which also happens to be the value of the default "Select One" option.

Comment: very close, embarrassingly I had the senior manager and manager fields all using the same ID.  Fixed and things are all smooth now.